# openpyxl, handle large Excel files

Tags: python-3.x, optimization, io, openpyxl

I use openpyxl for data processing.

First time, I write data copy code file to file (xlsx -> xlsx) for test.

```
# open input file
wb = load_workbook(filename='input.xlsx', read_only=True)
ws = wb['sheet name']

# create output file
out = Workbook(write_only=True)
out_sh = out.create_sheet('sheet name')

# copy data
for rows in ws:
   out_sh.append(cells.value for cells in rows)

# save file
out.save('output.xlsx')
wb.close()
out.close()
```

> input file size is **394 MB** and there is **6 sheets**.
> 5 sheets size is **1048576 rows by 17 (A~Q) columns**.
> My memory size is **8 GB and normally 66% in use (idle state, about 2.5 GB left)**.
> last one sheet size is small. i tested for **one large sheets**.

In openpyxl I use the **read_only** and **write_only** options for optimization but when I run the data copy code for **only 1 sheet** (not whole 394MB file), I get a **MemoryError**.

If data analysis code is added, it will only be able to process smaller files.

Are there any **optimization techniques** to large file processing I haven't tried yet?

Comment: when i try data copy for small sheet ( 410500 rows by 17 columns) but result are same. Memory Error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are other threads with same error issue:

[Memory Error Thread 1](https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/issues/1132/memoryerror-when-load_workbook)
[Memory Error Thread 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21875249/memory-error-using-openpyxl-and-large-data-excels)

Does it help with your problem?