# How write into excel after read chucksize

Tags: python-3.x

How write into excel file after read a file in chucksize?

I don't know how to write after read this 80k lines from file into excel via pandas
Thank you

```html
import os, sys
import pandas as pd
import xlwings as xw

caminho = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0]))
txt = caminho + '\\Fat3.txt'
xls = caminho + '\\cobfat.xlsx'
existe_txt = os.path.exists(txt)
existe_xls = os.path.exists(xls)


def check_path(x):
    # Função para verificar se há arquivo no caminho e com o nome correto. 
    if x != True:
        st = 'O arquivo não foi encontrado.\nVerifique se o nome está no local e com o nome correto.'
    else:
        st = 'ok'
    return st

big_file = 5000

if check_path(existe_txt):
    # Lista para guardados os dados do arquivo
    lst_xl = []

    # Leitura do arquivo usando chuck size
    for df in pd.read_csv(txt, sep="|", header=None, encoding='ISO-8859-1', chunksize=big_file):
        lst_xl.append(df)
        print('Gravando ...', df.shape)

    # Gravar dados no Excel
    df_xl = pd.concat(lst_xl, axis=0)
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx')
    df_xl.to_excel(writer,'Plan1')
    writer.save()
    # I get error "error memory limit exceeded" after try save this in file.
```

Stack trace of the `MemoryError`:

```
 File "C:\Users\marreco\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\et_xmlfile\xmlfile.py", line 41, in element yield File "C:\Users\marreco\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet_writer.py", line 146, in write_row write_cell(xf, self.ws, cell, cell.has_style) File "C:\Users\marreco\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\cell_writer.py", line 45, in etree_write_cell el = Element("c", attributes) MemoryError
```

Comment: Please can you post the full stack trace of your error message?

Comment: look
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\marreco\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\et_xmlfile\xmlfile.py", line 41, in element
    yield
  File "C:\Users\marreco\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\_writer.py", line 146, in write_row
    write_cell(xf, self.ws, cell, cell.has_style)
  File "C:\Users\marreco\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\cell\_writer.py", line 45, in etree_write_cell
    el = Element("c", attributes) **MemoryError**

Comment: I think the answers to this question might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21875249/memory-error-using-openpyxl-and-large-data-excels

Comment: I don't understand, I'm using pandas, then pandas use openpyxl in background, why I need manipulate openpyxl directly?
There is other way to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't belive the answear was all time so close.

```html
xw.Range('A1').value = df_xl
```

Thank you!