# MemoryError using OpenPyxl and insert_rows()

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, openpyxl

I have a script that opens up an excel worksheet (1.353 kB), updates row based on values and inserts new rows based on an index. Unfortunately, I get a MemoryError. Besides, the script is consuming a lot of RAM. Is this based on the code or this based on the library? Thank you for your support.

The error message is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "update_worksheet.py", line 42, in <module>
    update.add_row(idx)
  File "update_worksheet.py", line 30, in add_row
    self.__ws.insert_rows(idx)
  File ".\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\worksheet.py", line 713, in insert_rows
    self._move_cells(min_row=idx, offset=amount, row_or_col="row")
  File ".\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\worksheet.py", line 706, in _move_cells
    self._move_cell(row, column, row_offset, col_offset)
  File ".\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\worksheet.py", line 802, in _move_cell
    self._cells[new_row, new_col] = cell
MemoryError
```

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import pandas as pd
import time 

class UpdateWorksheet():
    def __init__(self,path):
        self.__wb = load_workbook(path, read_only = False)
        self.__ws = self.__wb["WP_Planning"]
        self.__df = pd.DataFrame(self.__ws.values)
    
    def search_value_in_col_idx(self, search_string, col_idx=1):
        try:
            idx = self.__df[self.__df[col_idx]==search_string].index.item()
            return idx
        except ValueError:
            return None  

    def update_status(self,row_idx, col_idx, status):
        self.__ws.cell(row = row_idx, column = col_idx).value = status

    def find_last_row(self, key, status):
        idx = None
        try:
            idx = self.__df[self.__df[1]=="HMI"].index.tolist()
        except ValueError:
            idx = None
        return idx[-1]        

    def add_row(self, idx):
        self.__ws.insert_rows(idx)
    
    def save_workbook(self,path):
        self.__wb.save(path)
        print("finish")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    path = './data/TrackingSheet.xlsx'
    update = UpdateWorksheet(path)
    index = update.search_value_in_col_idx("PFIVEDAIEX-4244",4)
    update.update_status(index,7,"Mikey")
    idx = update.find_last_row("PFIVEDAIEX-4244","Fixed")
    update.add_row(idx)
```

**Edit1:**

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl import Workbook
import pandas as pd

class UpdateWorksheet():
    def __init__(self,path):
        self.__path = path

    def load_file(self, read_only):
        wb = load_workbook(self.__path, read_only)
        return wb
   
    # Search line to be updated
    def search_value_in_col_idx(self, search_string, col_idx, ws):
        df = pd.DataFrame(ws.values)
        try:
            idx = df[df[col_idx]==search_string].index.item()
            return idx
        except ValueError:
            return None  

    # Update line attributes
    def update_status(self,row_idx, col_idx, status, ws):
        if not row_idx is None:
            ws.cell(row = row_idx, column = col_idx).value = status

    # Find last row for new rows
    def find_last_row(self,ws):
        df = pd.DataFrame(ws.values)
        idx = None
        try:
            idx = df[df[1]=="HMI"].index.tolist()
        except ValueError:
            idx = None
        return idx[-1]        

    # Add new rows
    def add_row(self,idx,ws):
        if idx is not None:
            ws.insert_rows(idx, 5)

    # Save changes made to workbook
    def save_workbook(self,wb):
        wb.save(self.__path)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    path = './data/TrackingSheet.xlsx'
    update = UpdateWorksheet(path)
    wb = update.load_file(read_only=True)
    idx = update.search_value_in_col_idx("PFIVEDAIEX-4244",4,wb["WP_Planning"])
    last_row = update.find_last_row(wb["WP_Planning"])
    wb.close()
    wb = update.load_file(read_only=False)
    update.update_status(idx,7,"Mikey",wb["WP_Planning"])
    update.add_row(200,wb["WP_Planning"])
    pdate.save_workbook(wb)
    wb.close()
```

Comment: This is already answered by https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21875249/memory-error-using-openpyxl-and-large-data-excels/21875423

Comment: Not exactly, everything works fine except the insert_rows function. As soon as insert_rows function is called, the memory usage increases rapidly finally leading to the error message shown in the original post.

Comment: Sounds like something else is going on as inserting a single row should not cause any problems. How big is the worksheet? And at what row are you inserting? BTW. this is horrible coding style.

Comment: @SergedeGossondeVarennes you can't edit Read-Only workbooks,

Comment: @CharlieClark, the implementation is bad, you're right. Anyways, I want to update rows based on a column value. That's working fine. In order to search the excel sheet, `load_workbook(path,read_only=True)` is enough. But right now, I have the problem that I also want to update certain rows, insert rows and do some kind of operations. So I have used `wb.close()` and load the excel sheet using `wb = load_workbook(path)` again. Updating values is fine, but using `wb.insert_rows(idx)` leads again to the old error. The file of the excel sheet is 1.353 kB and I try to insert the row at position 222.

Comment: How many rows in total?

Comment: @CharlieClark, not so many, like 700 rows and 50 columns. 10 different worksheets. How would you structure such a task? First, reading in the workbook, search for a row and then update the associated column values.

Comment: A file like that should not cause memory problems. Must be something else. Please continue the discussion on the mailing list.

Comment: @CharlieClark, I have updated the original code, the behaviour is still the same. Until the function call to update.add_row, everything is fast and robust. So I have no idea what's causing this problem.

Comment: At the end, limiting the columns in `cells = self.iter_rows(min_row=min_row,max_col=100)` in `move_cells` method from worksheet.py solved the problem. Beforehand, it iterated up to 16.000 which caused this time delay.